# Find the point on ellipse $4x^2+y^2=4$ that is furthest from $(1,0)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, conic-sections

The equation of an ellipse is $4x^2 + y^2 = 4$. Find the furthest point $(x,y)$ from $(1,0)$.

**Additional information from comment**: First, I transformed this equation into the general formula and the result I got was: $$\frac {x^2}1 + \frac{y^2}{2^2} = 1.$$

My professor used this formula to find the distance between the 2 points: $$\sqrt{(x-1)^2 + (y-0)^2}$$ but I don't understand where this formula comes from.

Comment: So what have you tried?

Comment: First, I transformed this equation into the general formula and the result I got was: (x^2/1) + (y^2/2^2) = 1. My professor used this formula to find the distance between the 2 points: ((x-1)^2 + (y-0)^2)^(1/2) but I don't understand where this formula comes from.

Comment: In single variable calculus you can just write $x = \cos t,$ $y = 2 \sin t.$ This traces the entire curve; just write out $(x-1)^2 + y^2$ and find that maximum

Comment: I know we can do this, the problem is I don't know where this formula comes from. I Know he is gonna use it to derivate it and find the maximum. But I wanna know how he got to that conclusion.

Comment: Differentiation is used to find max and min. You are asked to find a point on the ellipse such that it is the furthest  point from (x,y) on the ellipse to point (1,0).  We are trying to maximize a distance so that is why we want to differentiate the distance between the two.

Comment: @VirginiaMartínHerrera The next time you post a question keep in mind to write down what you have tried $= )$

Comment: I'm not clear on what you don't understand.  Is it (a) where the distance formula $\sqrt{(x-1)^2+(y-0)^2}$ comes from? (b) how to connect this with the formula for the ellipse? or (c) how to find the maximum from that connection?

Comment: the formula your professor gave is the distance between some (as of yet) unknown point $(x, y)$ and the point $(1,0)$

Comment: If it's (a), it's just the Pythagorean theorem, expressed in Cartesian coordinates.  For any point $(x, y)$ on the ellipse, visualize the right triangle with vertices $(1, 0)$, $(x, 0)$, and $(x, y)$.  The two legs have length $x-1$ and $y$.  The square of the hypotenuse is then the sum of the squares of the legs.  The formula comes from that.

Answer (score 1):

The diagram below depicts the ellipse, and the right triangle involved in the distance formula:

[image]

In this diagram, the point on the ellipse has coordinates $(x, y)$ in general.  (Here, I've chosen $x = -\frac12$ and $y = \sqrt{3}$, but it could be any point on the ellipse.)  The two legs are represented by the blue line segment, which has length $|x-1|$, and the green line segment, which has length $|y|$.  The hypotenuse—the orange line segment—is the desired distance $r$.

From Pythagoras, we have

$$
r^2 = (|x-1|)^2+(|y|)^2 = (x-1)^2+y^2
$$

where we can get rid of the absolute value because any real value $z$ and its absolute value $|z|$ have the same square.  Take the square root of both sides (since $r \geq 0$), and we get

$$
r = \sqrt{(x-1)^2+y^2}
$$

Comment: Very helpful answer here.  Visuals here can be so helpful for aiding explanations.

Answer (score 0):

The distance between 2 points (say $P(x_1, y_1)$ and $Q(x_2, y_2)$) in coordinate geometry is given by the following equation: $d= \sqrt{(x_1 - x_2)^2+(y_1 - y_2)^2}$. This equation is derived by constructing a right angle triangle between the points $P$ and $Q$, and using Pythagorus's theorem to find the length (or distance between the 2 points) of the hypotenuse. ([A link to an example of this sort](http://www.purplemath.com/modules/distform.htm))

So I believe your professor has said we are trying to find the distance between a point $(1,0)$ and it's furtherest point, $(x,y)$ (where $(x,y)$ is on the ellipse). Thus, the distance between the 2 points is $d= \sqrt{(x - 1)^2+(y - 0)^2}$.

Answer (score 0):

WLOG $(x,y)$ can be chosen to be $(\cos t,2\sin t)$

If $d$ is the distance between $(x,y);(1,0)$

$d^2=\cos^2t-2\cos t+1+4\sin^2t=5-2\cos t-3\cos^2t$

$=5+\dfrac13-3\left(\cos t+\dfrac13\right)^2\le5+\dfrac13$

Answer (score -1):

Let $d$ be the distance from the point $(1,0)$ to a point on the ellipse $(x,y)$, then $d^2 = (x-1)^2+y^2= (x-1)^2 + 4-4x^2= x^2-2x+1+4-4x^2 = -3x^2-2x+5 $. This is a quadratic function and you know it attains a max at $x = -\frac{b}{2a} = - \frac{-2}{2(-3)} = -\frac{1}{3}$. Thus $d^2_{\text{max}} = -3\left(\frac{-1}{3}\right)^2-2\left(\frac{-1}{3}\right)+5 = \frac{16}{3}$ . So $d_{\text{max}} = \dfrac{4}{\sqrt{3}}$. Hope this helps !

Comment: Why sentence $1$?  Why sentence $2$?  Please explain your post; for the asker's sake, no?

Comment: At any rate, I've reported your retaliatory downvotes.

Comment: Thank you all!!!! You're amazing!